# Smooth stochastic differential equations

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Research on stochastic differential equations seems to be exclusively focused on the Brownian motion noise, where the solution is a nowhere differentiable function.

I am instead interested in stochastic equations of the form

$$dy/dt=f(y)+e(t),$$

where $e(t)$ is a smooth random function, e.g. a smooth Gaussian process.

Is there any interesting theory about such equations? I'm specifically interested in parameter inference, but any other references will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think such a theory exists.

My understanding of stochastic SDEs is that they're a reinterpretation of a stochastic integral; that is, a stochastic SDE can be rewritten as a stochastic integral, and it is in terms of said integrals we should think of stochastic SDEs.

A key property of stochastic integrals is that they are continuous-time martingales, and there your project ends because *all continuous-time martingales are time-shifted Brownian motion*. That is, for any continuous-time martingale $M$ there is a Brownian motion $B$ s.t. $M_t = B_{\langle M, M \rangle_t}$ for all $t$, with $\langle M, M \rangle_t$ being the quadratic variation of $M$. Since $B$ is nowhere differentiable $M$ is nowhere differentiable; this includes all stochastic integrals.

Brownian motion is special because it is the *only* Gaussian process that is also a martingale and has independent increments (two properties that turn out to be redundant; one implies the other). I'm pretty sure no one knows of a differentiable process that is also a martingale; it certainly isn't a Gaussian process if it exists (and I don't think it does).

In short, talking about SDEs involving smooth stochastic processes means we would need to abandon martingales and build a brand new theory for stochastic integration. No one is in any hurry to do that.

Comment: "Brownian motion is special because it is the only Gaussian process that is also a martingale" Worse, I believe it is the only Gaussian process that is even a semimartingale. By Bichteler Dellacherie, this makes it the only Gaussian process we can define a stochastic integral against.

Comment: At least fBm is not a semimartingale and I don't really know any continuous Gaussian processes other than that, lol

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's much literature - most stochastic processes we care about are not differentiable.

However if there is a particular case you're interested in you can simply solve things pathwise - no stochastic calculus involved.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Gaussian process can be interpreted as a solution of the stochastic heat equation (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850049/intuitive-explanation-of-a-stochastic-pde?rq=1)), my impression is that it should be possible to reframe the equation you're interested in as one driven by white noise. It would probably be second order, though.